# Getting Control of RadioButton WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here what i have in xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header = "Base" Width="100">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" GroupName="{Binding Index}" Name="ABCD" Content="ABCD" IsChecked="True" Checked="radioButton_Checked"/>
                     <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" GroupName="{Binding Index}" Name="XYZ" Content="XYZ" Checked="radioButton_Checked" />
                  </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Here are some codes in some function (any) xaml.cs:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
FrameworkElement radioButton = dataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as FrameworkElement;
radioButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

I can hide the visibility as I am hiding whole cell. but i want to change a radio button content in runtime from "XYZ" to "HAHAHA". How can i achieve this?

Comment: Best way would be to bind the Content. What is the itemssource of your DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a value converter to achieve this. This can be used to change the name based on the index value;

```
public class IndexToXYZOrHaHaHaConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var index = (int) value;
        if (index > 10)
        {
            return "XYZ";
        }
        return "HaHaHa";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You'll need to create an instance of the class by adding a static resource to your resource dictionary.

```
<local:IndexToXYZOrHaHaHaConverter x:Key="IndexToXYZOrHaHaHaConverter"/>
```

You'll then need to change the content of the radio button from "xyz" to this;

```
Content="{Binding Index, Converter={StaticResource IndexToXYZOrHaHaHaConverter}}"
```

This should dynamically switch the value between xyz and HaHaHa depending on the index. In the example I gave this depends on whether the value is greater or less than 10, which is probably not what you want so you'll have to fix the logic. I've also assumed that index is an integer, you may need to change that too if index is something else.

Converters are great for setting properties based on bound values that don't directly correspond to the value they are bound to e.g. converting a string to a color.

Hope this is of some help.